# SharePoint 2010 | Web.UserIsSiteAdmin not respondig with true

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i'm developing a SP2010 Webpart as WSP-WebPartSolution

I check if User is SiteCollection Admin and Show more Details

```
if (SPContext.Current.Web.UserIsSiteAdmin == true) ...
```

the WebPart is displayed on the MainSite of the SiteCollection in a Variation

I'm logged in with a User set as SiteCollectionAdmin in SiteActions/SiteSettings/Site Collection Administrators and it answers with false.

What did i wrong? How can i read if loggedIn user is SiteCollectionAdmin.
Reading

```
SPContext.Current.Web.SiteAdministrators;
```

as not SiteCollectionAdmin throws the User Out of SharePoint with AccessDenied

Comment: this issue is solved - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SPUser.IsSiteAdmin property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.issiteadmin.aspx) from the CurrentUser:

```
if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin)
{
    // DO STUFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was confused by the namespaces - that did it